# np fast random sampling with boolean "filter"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm wondering if there is a way to speed up the following piece of code using numpy.
The only value I'm interested in is the `points_within_distance`, the numpy array can be discarded or modified if needed.

```
for _ in range(SAMPLE_SIZE):
     random_point = (random.uniform(0, cube.length), random.uniform(0, cube.length))
     if distance_to_center(random_point, cube) <= sphere.r:
         points_within_distance += 1
```

This currently clocks around 0.750ms for a sample size of 1000.

I have tried

```
samples = np.random.random_sample((SAMPLE_SIZE, 2)) * cube.length # random sample of SAMPLE_SIZE

for row in samples:
   if distance_to_center(row, cube) < sphere.r:
        points_within_distance += 1
```

However this clearly is even more inefficient and clocks in at around 1.2 ms.

I'm not quite sure how to go about using masks in this scenario or if masks is even the right thing here to utilize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By avoiding a for loop I think  it can speed up much more. I mean generate samples all at once and compare all at one. Something like:

```
x = np.random.uniform(0, cube.length, size=SAMPLE_SIZE)
y = np.random.uniform(0, cube.length, size=SAMPLE_SIZE)

distance = np.square(x - x_center) + np.square(y - y_center)
points_within_distance = (distance <= r**2).sum()
```

I tested it using IPython's `%%timeit` for sample size of 1000. and it says: `129 µs ± 3.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`